# Selecting Item from List - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, sublist

I have a list that contains a "sublist" like so:

`list = [['0','1'],['2','3']]`

Is there any way I can select only the "sublist" `['0','1']` and perform functions with it? Is there a method similar to "get" for dictionaries but for lists that I can use...?

Comment: `list[0]`  will return the first element which is ['0', '1'] but you should definitely not name your variable `list`

Comment: Oh okay gotcha, that was simpler than I've made it to be. Thank you so much, the variable will not be named "list" in the code I promise! :)

Comment: @Arsonist'sSpoils - you can get more familiar and play with *small* program here -https://pythontutor.com/   to *visualize* the underlying Data Structure.